# A problem for the uniform convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis

$A_{j,k}$ is non-negative numbers, $1\leq j,k<\infty$. suppose that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}=1,\forall j\in \mathbb{N_+};\quad \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}A_{j,k}=0,\forall k\in \mathbb{N_+}.$$
let $B_k$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers, then prove$$\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}\cdot B_k=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} B_k$$

If we can prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}\cdot B_k$ converges uniformly, then we can change the lim and the infinite sum. I tried to use the uniform convergence of series and Abel formula but I failed.

Comment: Sure you got your indices right ($j,k$ instead of $k,j$)? Otherwise $A_{1,j}=1$ and $A_{k,j}=0$ for $k>1$ gives a simple counterexample for any $\lim B_k \not =0$.

Comment: Switching the limit and the sum will not give you the desired result as $\sum \lim_j A_{j,k}B_k = 0$

Comment: Yes, I got the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first show that $B_k \to 0$ implies $\sum_k A_{j,k}B_k \to 0$. So let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\abs{B_k} < \frac\epsilon2$ for $k \ge N$, and $J \in \mathbb N$ such that $|A_{j,k}| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2\sum_{k=1}^N \abs{B_k}+1}$ for $j \ge J$ and all $k \le N$. Then we have for these $j$: 
\begin{align*}
 \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}B_k}
   &\le \abs{\sum_{k=1}^N A_{j,k} B_k} + \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty A_{j,k}\abs{B_k}\\
   &\le \frac{\epsilon}{2\sum_{k=1}^N \abs{B_k}+1}\sum_{k=1}^N \abs{B_k} + \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty A_{j,k} \cdot \frac\epsilon 2\\
    &\le \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Now suppose $B_k \to B$, then $B_k - B \to 0$, hence 
$$ 0\leftarrow \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}(B_k - B) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}B_k - \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}B = \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k} - B\iff 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{j,k}B_k \to B $$